# リモートのJupyter notebook上で大規模計算を実行し、sshが切れても計算し続けるようにする。

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook

私はサーバーマシンのscreen command windowでJupyter notebookを以下のように起動し、ローカルマシンで リモートで接続してJupyter notebookを使っています。 しかし、2日〜2,3週間かかる計算をJupyter notebook上で実行した後にsshの接続を切ったあと、再度remoteのscreen windowで動いている、同じJupyter notebookに接続しても、計算が途中で終わってしまっています。sshが切れてJupyter notebookのウィンドウが落ちてもJupyter notebookのセルの実行が中断されない方法はありませんでしょうか。 よろしくお願いいたします。

* remoteで

```
screen
ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

でjupyter notebookを開いたあと
* localで

```
ssh -N -f -L 8888:localhost:8889 remote_user@remote_host
```

でjupyter notebookに接続をしています。 sshを切ったあとは再度

```
ssh -N -f -L 8888:localhost:8889 remote_user@remote_host
```

と接続をして計算を実行していたnotebookに戻っています.

Answer (score 3):

英語版に同じような質問があります。
[Keep Jupyter notebook running after closing browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539832)

それによると、ブラウザーを閉じても計算は続けるけど、出力先が無くなってしまうので結果が出力されないためだそうです。

最も簡単な解決方法は、%%captureというセルマジックを使って、`stdout`, `stderr`, IPython の`display() calls`をキャプチャーすることだそうです。

```
%%capture output
# 以下に時間のかかるコードを書く
```

そうすると出力はすべて`output`という変数に保存されるので、再接続後に次のコマンドですべての出力が表示できるそうです。

```
output.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/NII-cloud-operation/Jupyter-LC_wrapper

これを使うと browser が落ちても実行中（実行の指示が Kernel に伝わっている）セルの出力は wrapper kernel がファイルに保存するので、結果の確認が可能です。

また、別のアプローチとしては.. papermil (https://github.com/nteract/papermill) を利用するという方法も考えられます。